# How to compile a Rust binary for L4Re?

Tags: rust, microkernel, l4re

[L4Re](https://l4re.org/) is a microkernel based system written in C++. It comes with a couple of [packages](https://svn.l4re.org/repos/oc/l4re/trunk/l4/pkg/) mainly written in C++, C, and it seems like there is native support for Fortran, OCaml and Perl.

There is also an [hello world package](https://svn.l4re.org/repos/oc/l4re/trunk/l4/pkg/hello/server/src/main.c) written in plain C, compiled and linked normally, but with the l4re toolchain.

Is it possible to build a hello world Rust program against that L4Re toolchain in order to write L4Re packages in Rust?

I am aware of [rust-cross](https://github.com/japaric/rust-cross), but there is probably no suitable triple available for my situation and I need to [specify](https://github.com/japaric/rust-cross#target-specification-files) my target manually. Any ideas which values should be used in my case?

Comment: What is the architecture that the kernel runs on / you are targeting? What calling convention(s) do L4Re applications use?

Comment: Everything is amd64 in my case. I'm not sure about the calling conventions. There is a working Makefile framework for building around, but I don't completely understand how it works. Probably the main point is, that it provides its own modified [uclibc](https://svn.l4re.org/repos/oc/l4re/trunk/l4/pkg/l4re-core/uclibc/), which I need to compile against.

Comment: From a deleted answer: The paper ["Rust On L4Re — Integrating A Modern Systems Language Into A Microkernel Userland"](https://www.crustulus.de/downloads/Rust%20On%20L4Re.pdf) may provide some relevant information about the progress of support for Rust on L4Re, along with guidance on dealing with toolchain and library issues.